# Regex to extract emails not working

Tags: regex, import.io

I am trying to extract all the email addresses from pages like this

http://www.quiltguilds.com/alabama.htm

I am using the following RegEX to extract all the emails.

```
\w+@\w*\.\w*
```

While this works at online Regex checkers, this isn't working with the import.io application where I am trying to use this to extract all emails.

Can someone kindly review the Regex and confirm if this one would work for extracting just email addresses from a block of text

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
 \S+\@\S+
```

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly :)